# IE9 Input Form type=file, manually edit text field

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9

I'm looking to improve one of my company's web applications to support IE9.

One of the issues I'm having is with the input field. In IE8, a user could use the input form field to select a file, then manually edit the textual contents of the text box to, for instance, select a host folder of a file, or what have you.

In IE9, it seems that the text box is not editable. You click browse to select a file in the dialog window, and then the textbox from that point is locked.

Is there any attribute I can set to alter this behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, **IE8** introduced the read-only text box for File Upload, and it was not changed in IE9. There's no mechanism to turn off that behavior.

To change the contents of the box, simply click the Browse button and select or paste in the new filename.